# How to split read and write operations to endpoints provided by Postgresql cluster in Loopback 3?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

This is actually confusing, I've googled almost everything. I've found here, on stackoverflow, how to have multiple data sources, but how to split READ and WRITE operations per data sources is nowhere to be found? I have AWS RDS aurora postgresql cluster in here and 2 endpoints available. One for write node and another one for read nodes, which will load balance between read replicas.

Apparently sending queries to different endpoints should be done in application level (which is strange). And I can't find how Postgresql Connector in Loopback could help in here. There's nothing even near in documentation about this quite usual use-case. Anyone could please provide a sample how this is done please?

Comment: I dont see any option because model gets intialised with the data source. May be you can programatically create readonly model using second datasource and use that one for read only operaiton.